# Are the parameters of saved exposed Views filters saved in the database, and if so, how can I access it?

Tags: views

So in a View (using Views 3) we can expose filters and these filters are "saveable" by particular users, where is this saved, and can I access it?

I want to be able to "save" the parameters and then be able to email the user later with updated search results periodically...

I'm assuming that if no filters have been applied, the view will display all of the content...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Saved Searches](http://drupal.org/project/savedsearches)

> Saved Searches provides a simple workflow for saving search queries
>   from Drupal core search. It will take advantage of Apache Solr facets,
>   if the [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module is installed.
>
> Saved Searches gives users with permission access to a "save this
>   search" form in a block, which appears on search result pages, and
>   lists the user's saved searches in another block. Depending on a
>   user's permissions, Saved Searches will provide a simple "Save this
>   search" button, a text field for entering a short URL slug, and/or a
>   dropdown to "Re-use an existing saved search name". Clicking the "Save
>   this search" button without entering a URL slug will generate a short
>   URL for the search, like "http://example.com/s/cwmc". A link to the
>   search will appear in the savedsearches_user block.
>
> Saved Searches is useful for sites with complex search options, or
>   sites where users may want to revisit or share dynamic sets of search
>   results.